# Mouse and Keyboard stopped working after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, usb, login-screen

Mouse and Keyboard stopped working after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. So I guess it's because the USBs ceased to work. Though I can reach the login screen, I can't really log in as I have no way to input anything. I've searched quite a lot on-line. But for all similar issues that I found, people were suggested to tackle the problem by terminal interactions. But with a paralyzed keyboard, the options are fairly limited to me.

I appreciate if anyone can share me a hint. Thanks!!